# Get number of lines changed between two tags in azure devops repos using rest api

Tags: git, rest, azure-devops

I'm trying to get the lines of code that has been changed (added, edited or deleted) between two tags in Azure Devops repos using the following apis

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/diffs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

It seems the `changeCounts` in response represent the file changes not the lines of code changes.

Then I tried to use the single commit id in the response to hit the following endpoint - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

It doesn't help as it doesn't have all the commits.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried it with two different branches by the following URL.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/diffs/commits?baseVersion=main&targetVersion=develop&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Please keep in mind, if you swap `baseVersion` with `targetVersion` you'll not get the count. `baseVersion` should be behind the `targetVersion`

---

If you want to compare two commits then you've to specify `baseVersionType=commit` and `targetVersionType=commit`

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/diffs/commits?baseVersion=288a82985bbb725a23699a9d15b9d23b6510f689&baseVersionType=commit&targetVersion=8379363a3154627993f2c358cee347b7c64bc836&targetVersionType=commit&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Comment: The `diffs/commits` endpoint provides changes in files not in lines of code